# How to get the enterpriseToken when creating an enterprise with the Android Management API?

Tags: android, google-api, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I'm trying to create a new enterprise using api method.
First I maked [signupUrls.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/signupUrls/create) with request parameters **projectId** and **callbackUrl**. In field **callbackUrl**, I put my Google Cloud platform admin url. 
And I got a response

```
{
  "name": "signupUrls/C78787fa85be23de9f",
  "url": "https://play.google.com/work/adminsignup?token=SAEQ6V4kHngQPk5wCSl37KkZPlfw-wJtlVHndDfsmH1R1twiXM1LC6FpYFSndpEaw2mbsmqd3T5eBaRWtQPrVClngJHZcKaGc0V_4dOhz-F8D0vSjb_1MnxRheUP0Ij8el6zNE5GYYA1LOECCUFLip8kcg6e99_3DfNbmutqHONjhdi8hQBQUa0Q5nWN-nMRF3EUgffvLk1zo4BAA0AUscQ"
}
```

The next point is method: [enterprises.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises/create) with **projectId**, **signupUrlName** and **enterpriseToken** parameters.

And then I send request I get erorr:

```
"message": "The enterprise token is invalid: SAEQ6V4kHngQPk5wCSl37KkZPlfw-wJtlVHndDfsmH1R1twiXM1LC6FpYFSndpEaw2mbsmqd3T5eBaRWtQPrVClngJHZcKaGc0V_4dOhz-F8D0vSjb_1MnxRheUP0Ij8eCUFLip8kcg6e99_3DfNbmutqHONjhdi8hQBQUa0Q5nWN-nMRF3EUgffBWwGHSA8AkFWvLk1zo4BAA0AUscQ",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

In the field **enterpriseToken** I put token values from **signupUrls.create** url response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the `enterpriseToken` you (or your customer) need to go through the enterprise sign-up flow by visiting the `url` returned by `signupUrls.create`, which looks like `https://play.google.com/work/adminsignup?token=...` (the token in this URL is **not** the `enterpriseToken`).

Upon completing the sign-up flow you will be redirected to the `callbackUrl` passed in `signupUrls.create`, with the `enterpriseToken` appended as a parameter. So if you set the `callbackUrl` to `https://example.com/mycallback` you will be redirected to a URL like `https://example.com/mycallback?enterpriseToken=...`.

You then need to extract the `enterpriseToken` and pass it to `enterprises.create`.

So if you create the enterprise yourself you can set any `callbackUrl`, even an invalid one, and just copy the `enterpriseToken` manually. However if you want your customer to create the enterprise then the `callbackUrl` should point to your server so you can retrieve the `enterpriseToken`, you may also want to pass an additional token in the `callbackUrl` so you can identify your customer.

More details in the guide for [creating an enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise).

Comment: Thanks, successfully created a new enterprise. Could you tell me is there some kind of admin control panel where I can view and manage devices?

Comment: Glad it worked. There is no console for the Android Management API, this API is meant to be called by EMMs (device management service providers) who are building their own console. If you would like to use an EMM you can browse the [list on the Android Enterprise website](https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/emm/). Using an EMM solution is simpler than using the API directly, but on the flip side it's also less flexible and usually isn't free.

Comment: Hi @Fred Using Android Management API  is free or is there any pricing attached to it ? Also is how we can created multiple enterprises as the default Android Management support only 1000 devices?

Comment: Android Management API is free. To go beyond the quota of 1000 devices / project, just [join the EMM community](https://developers.google.com/android/management/join).

Comment: hello @Ankur can you tell me where you found out that AMAPI supports only 1000 devices.

Comment: Documentation and comment from Fred confirmed that.

Comment: hi @Fred I've try to create the enterprise android management api in web application, i need eneterprisetoken, but that have only generate code and scopes not in enterpriseToken my callback URL having https://example.com/mycallback?code=`redirectcode`&scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement
could you please provide any relevant solutions